# How do I conduct a command on all the files in a directory and move the output for each file to a new folder?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I would like to conduct a command on each file in a directory and store the output in a new directory such that it has the same filename as the input. The command that I run is a .pl script has the format:

test.pl inputfile outputfile

For example, I have a directory named **input** with the files:
testa.txt
testb.txt

I run a for loop that conducts a command on those two files:

```
for file in /Users/test/Desktop/input
do
    test.pl $file /Users/test/Desktop/output/$file
done
```

However, providing the output path this way does not work. I keep getting the error no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` gets the value `/Users/test/Desktop/input`, so `test.pl` receives `/Users/test/Desktop/output//Users/test/Desktop/input` as the last argument. You'll want to use a [glob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) like `/Users/test/Desktop/input/*` and then stripping the directories using `basename`:

```
for file in /Users/test/Desktop/input/*
do
    test.pl "$file" "/Users/test/Desktop/output/$(basename "$file")"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

`xargs` is a tool that reads a list of files form `stdin` and executes a command on each filename it gets.
You need to pay attention to filenames containing a blanks.
I'd suggest you to provide more details for a more precise answer. The man page has plenty of details.